# How to Manually craft the Authorization header for Github in Python?

Tags: python, python-requests, github-api

Im using `requests` Python module to access Github's API. Github responses 404 Not Found, as [expected](https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/#basic-authentication).

This is my code:

```
import requests
import sys

username = sys.argv[1]
password = sys.argv[2]

url = 'https://api.github.com/{}'.format(username)
print(url)
response = requests.get(url, data={'password': password})
print(response)
```

How this header must be done?

I need to get the user's id!

Thanks!

Comment: Use a personal access token and URL format `https://myusername:mytoken@api.github.com`. You don't need to manually create an auth header.